# Only meta/inf file available when exploring jar content

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to read the content of a jar in a folder accessible from the root directory of my project, the jar is correctly found, however, my code only prints the name of the `META-INF` file, here's what i tried so far:

```
public static void provideClassList(String jarName) {


    List<String> classNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ZipInputStream zip;
    try {
        zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(StaticValues.JARS_PATH.concat(jarName)));
        for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
           System.out.println(entry);//PRINTS META-INF/
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.');
                classNames.add(className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length()));
            }
            zip.close();
        }

        // explore content (THIS IS ACTUALLY EMPTY)
        for (String className : classNames) {
            try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
                System.out.println(clazz.getCanonicalName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

I cant see any permissioning issue, also, i have opened the jar file manually from console and the content that i expect to find is all there.
Those are the properties i see from eclipse:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but if you just want to list all the files, there is no need for a ZipInputStream (which actually goes through the whole file). Use `ZipFile` instead.

Comment: @CarstenHoffmann i need to instantiate an object of each type of class contained in the jar  which is in my buildpath,  and invoke a method on it ,will try ZipFile, thx

Comment: hi i'm the owner of the question, as you can see the resolution of the problem is not really related to the question, could you please close? as this can be misleading for other users and since its useless, it will only consume space in your db
thx

Comment: Then definitely use ZipFile and not the ZipInputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `zip.close();` inside of the for loop, that is propably the reason you only get the first entry in the jar. Move it outside of the for loop, or even better, use a try-with-resources Statement.

```
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(StaticValues.JARS_PATH.concat(jarName);
     ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(fis)) {
  // code for iterating goes here
}
```